# how to add qml file in swipeview

Tags: javascript, html, c++, qt, qml

I was trying to use swipe view
In swipe view i need to add qml file into it
so every swipe i need to get one qml file to show
i need to get 7 qml file in 7 swipe and i need add global property in every swipe view

I try to loader to get qml file but i am not able to add global property
Because the qml file are already used in another swipe view i need to use global property and change the value

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Page
{

    id:mfcscreens

    Rectangle{
        height:wavescreen.height
        width: wavescreen.width

        SwipeView{
            id:swipeview
            anchors.fill:parent
            currentIndex: 0
            spacing: 4


            Item {
                id:page1
                Loader{
                    id:mainwavescreen
                    source: "MfcWavefoam.qml"
                }
            }
            Item {
                id:page2

                Loader{
                    id:leads12
                    source: "Leads12.qml"
                    Item{
                        property int speed: 5;
                        property int gain: 10;
                        property int xValue: 976
                        property int degreeValue: 143

                    }

                }

           }
            Item {
                id:page3
                Loader{
                    id:leads3of1
                    source: "Leads3of1.qml"
                }
            }
            Item {
                id:page4
                Loader{
                    id:leads3of2
                    source: "Leads3of2.qml"
                }
            }
            Item {
                id:page5
                Loader{
                    id:leads3of3
                    source: "Leads3of3.qml"
                }
            }
            Item {
                id:page6
                Loader{
                    id:leads3of4
                    source: "Leads3of4.qml"
                }
            }
            Item {
                id:page7
                Loader{
                    id:leads6of1
                    source: "Leads6of1.qml"
                }

            }
            Item {
                id:page8
                Loader{
                    id:leads6of2
                    source: "Leads6of2.qml"
                }

            }


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this stage, from what you convey in your use case, `Loader` isn't required. Particularly if the number of Pages in your `SwipeView` is static. Then, you definitely do not need to use `Loader`.

The following demonstrates:

- A `SwipeView` with 3 pages
- Each page in their own qml file
- The parent page has a global `speed`, `gain`, `xValue` and `degreeValue` property defined which all the children `Pages` can view and modify

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    property int speed: 5
    property int gain: 10
    property int xValue: 976
    property int degreeValue: 143
    SwipeView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        MfcWaveform { }
        Leads12 { }
        Leads3of1 { }
    }
}

// MfcWaveform.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Text {
            text: qsTr("MfcWaveform")
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Speed: %1").arg(speed)
            onClicked: speed = speed + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Gain: %1").arg(gain)
            onClicked: gain = gain + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("xValue: %1").arg(xValue)
            onClicked: xValue = xValue + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("degreeValue: %1").arg(degreeValue)
            onClicked: degreeValue = degreeValue + 1
        }
    }
}

// Leads12.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Leads12")
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Speed: %1").arg(speed)
            onClicked: speed = speed + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Gain: %1").arg(gain)
            onClicked: gain = gain + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("xValue: %1").arg(xValue)
            onClicked: xValue = xValue + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("degreeValue: %1").arg(degreeValue)
            onClicked: degreeValue = degreeValue + 1
        }
    }
}

// Leads3of1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Leads3of1")
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Speed: %1").arg(speed)
            onClicked: speed = speed + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Gain: %1").arg(gain)
            onClicked: gain = gain + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("xValue: %1").arg(xValue)
            onClicked: xValue = xValue + 1
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("degreeValue: %1").arg(degreeValue)
            onClicked: degreeValue = degreeValue + 1
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAJNXic7VRda8IwFH3PrwjCQBnUde6DFfYyH8bAwUTR51Bvu7A0qWk6FfG/L2lrFq3dg2wP28xLmnsOOefeHEqTVEiFh2qY0/AN0Z2j1xdcScEy9EJiwGuE9UqlSEGqFaZc4SwFmAX4uo7EhPIA+xd1ZDkhLIcA393e1MEZxBKgYvhXvYIxWtAUJhQWlQWzCA9fhcy8iDIW4JRI4MqCz1E4Je8QCZngNd7Y+gDILPMv67WeiHxb3aANQt2ue4s3T9jecBpntVcfkJXIVYbcGfYFyxNeIgd6CnUvIJ94ra8xLF2+WUqXAjzPxrLdcgy3Opb12epDrpTgX1wwKp/zzG91PCLjdvG8nR264H2m2zK0AsX31X6O/WMkH4ucWEUTm0ZBA2q9YjtSbhs+K1gWGiVLWItWH0fK7sTaajvVRgMOR7twT3Ur2+BWMf+G0P58Ziuvp7welvs/eTW/4N+TWOP2lNnDcn8+sx+FiYQv)